# How to use a proxy with the C# Neo4jClient?

Tags: neo4jclient

How does one route [Neo4jClient](https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient) connections through a proxy?

The client accepts an `IHttpClient` in the `GraphClient` constructor except that is an internal type which doesn't expose any proxy properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below works as of [1.1.0.32](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Neo4jClient/) where `proxyUri` would be something like `http://myproxy.net:8080`

```
var graphUri = new Uri(ConnectionConfig.GraphUri);
var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();

httpClientHandler.Proxy = new WebProxy(ConnectionConfig.ProxyUri, true);
httpClientHandler.UseProxy = true;

var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
var httpClientWrapper = new HttpClientWrapper(ConnectionConfig.Username, ConnectionConfig.Password, httpClient);
_graphClient = new GraphClient(graphUri, httpClientWrapper);
```